# How to make a UILabel into a centered paragraph so the lines won't go off the screen

Tags: swift3

but the text is too long. I was wondering how i could make it so that the line stay within the view, increase the number of lines, and be centered. I think i have to use something with NSParagraphStyle? maybe? thanks! [image]

Comment: I recommend you check out TTTAttributedLabel. It helps in situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set width constaints on the label and use labelname.numberoflines = 0 it automatically adjusts for screen width. also include labelname.alignment = .center